# Is it possible to failover Azure functions using a VSTS/Azure DevOps Release deployment task?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

I have a timer triggered function that I'm looking to deploy in two different regions in an active-passive pattern. In disaster recovery scenario, I want to disable the active instance, then activate the passive instance in such a way that I can also keep record of this activity.

I know this can be done via powershell/Azure CLI, but I think doing this via Azure release pipelines should be better for auditing purposes. Does anyone know if this is doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I donot know much about Azure funtions. But there are [azure powershell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops) and [azure CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops) that you can use to run the scripts in azure release pipeline, Since it can be done via powershell/Azure CLI.

In order to run the powershell/Azure CLI scripts in azure release pipeline. You need first connect your azure devops to your Microsoft Azure subscription via service connection. Check here to create a [service connection](http://connect%20to%20your%20Microsoft%20Azure%20subscription,) in azure devops. This service connection is needed for `azureSubscription` parameter of azure powershell task/azure cli task

Then you can create a release pipeline and add azure powershell task or azure cli task to run the scripts.